# Remove NAs returned from grid_terrain()

Tags: r, lidr

I have several tiles in a catalog covering bays along the shore. There are some hits in the water but they are sparse. Ideally I think I should use the `is_concave = TRUE` as an option in `grid_terrain()`, but it was taking so long I ended up terminating R.

I looked at the resulting terrain rasters that had the "outside the convex hull" warning - they had a small area of extreme negative values due to the NAs in the water area. Is it possible to remove the NAs?

Data may be downloaded from [NS elevation explorer](https://nsgi.novascotia.ca/datalocator/elevation/) (search for 284_4955).

```
library(lidR)

myLas <- readLAS("284_4955_201901.laz", filter = "-drop_withheld -drop_overlap -drop_z_below -1")
x <- grid_terrain(myLas, 1, tin())
#> Interpolation of 89 points outside the convex hull defined by ground points (outside the triangulation) failed and returned NAs.

x
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 1000, 1000, 1e+06  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent     : 284000, 285000, 4955000, 4956000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=utm +zone=20 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +vunits=m +no_defs 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : Z 
#> values     : -21474836, 106.02  (min, max)
```

2 diagonal black lines are negative raster values which I think come from the NAs.
[image: 2 diagonal black lines are negative raster values]

Comment: You problem is likely to be reproducible with a LAS object. Please simplify your question to make it minimally reproducible. Moreover I'm not sure to understand. `normalize_height` is likely to complain about NAs but not `grid_terrain()`. This is why we need a minimal reproducible example and ideally a link to the point cloud or at least an image.

Comment: Thank you, I've simplified the code and included an image in the edits of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, those cases of fractal-ish costal region with sparse points in water are nasty. And your files is special: points classified as water are also flagged withheld. So using `drop_withheld` discards all water points. In addition I think you found an edge case bug (when you see -21474836 you are in presence of an infinite value). So here are some options available for you.

#### Keep water points

```r
myLas <- readLAS("284_4955_201901.laz", filter = "-drop_z_below -1 -keep_class 2 9")
x <- grid_terrain(myLas, 1, tin())
plot(x)
```

[image]

#### Increase extrapolation outide convex hull limits

See documentation of `tin()` and `knnidw()`

```r
myLas <- readLAS("284_4955_201901.laz", filter = "-drop_withheld -drop_overlap -drop_z_below -1 -keep_class 2 9")
x <- grid_terrain(myLas, 1, tin(extrapolate = knnidw(3, 1, 75)))
plot(x)
```

[image]

#### Erase infinites

Erase infinite values that actually are in water at the very edge of the convex hull.

```r
myLas <- readLAS("284_4955_201901.laz", filter = "-drop_withheld -drop_overlap -drop_z_below -1 -keep_class 2 9")
x <- grid_terrain(myLas, 1, tin())
x[x < 0] <- 0
plot(x)
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, thank you. I think in my case extending the extrapolation with knnidw is ideal and safer than my initial request. This should reduce/eliminate the infinite value but can be double checked aftterwards.

Comment: To be correct I proposed to extend the limits of the extrapolation with knnidw(). This task is always performed but knnidw does not interpolate if there is no point less that 50 m away. Here I choose 75 m. This is a typical problem already encountered by other users in costal region

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to JRR's answer of removing infinites is to set NA values to NaN. In this way ArcGIS will read these as noData rather than a number. (I chose < -1 because it's below what I used in the filter for reading the las.)

```
myLas <- readLAS("284_4955_201901.laz", filter = "-drop_withheld -drop_overlap -drop_z_below -1")
x <- grid_terrain(myLas, 1, tin())

x[x < -1] <- NaN
NAvalue(x) <- NaN  # not sure if needed.
    
writeRaster(x, "dtm.tif", naflag = -9999)
```